# Change JBoss AS7 Session ID format

Tags: jboss

I just installed JBoss AS7 and I saw that session id format has changed.
e.g. D9PL+U9MOZ6hee1Qqm1bsh6M.node01

Can I change the format to match the old one (Alphanumeric(char32))?
e.g. BF8452E2C7D3822017116A56E61FCBD0

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

What profile you run AS7 with? E.g. standalone-ha.xml has mod_cluster subsystem enabled and it appends node identity (node01). However, I might not be getting your question right...

Comment: I'm using standalone.xml. The point is that JBoss adds symbols like '+' or '.' to the sessionid and i don't want that. I want to be only alphanumeric. Thank you